# What are interesting heuristics of determining how far given matrix is from a singular one?

Tags: matrices, na.numerical-analysis, matrix-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

The condition number and volume of matrix (defined as absolute value of its determinant) are things which come to mind. Is there more?

I think that over the years numerical folks (who are faced with this problem more often than the others) must have  accumulated a number of interesting ideas. I would like to peek into those ideas, no matter how useless and obscure they turned out to be.

Comment: You should search for: "numerical rank"

Comment: Why "heuristics"? The two examples that you mention are rigorously defined measures.

Answer (score 4):

The distance (in operator norm) from square matrix $A$ to the set of singular matrices is the minimum of the singular values of $A$.  This is easy to see from the singular value decomposition.

Answer (score 4):

Another interesting concept in this direction is the [pseudospectrum](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Pseudospectrum).

(sorry for the one-line answer).